# ¿Como puedo crear un metodo para cambiar el valor de un atributo?

Tags: java

Escribe en Java una clase llamada `MiNumero`. Los métodos de la clase deben ser:

- Constructor sin parámetros (establecerá el número a cero)
- Constructor con parámetro entero (asignará ese valor al número)
- Método `cambiaNumero(int)`: permite asignar un nuevo valor al número

El código:

```
public class MiNumero {
    private int Valor;
    private int camValor;

    public int getCamValor() {
        return camValor;
    }
    public void setCamValor(int camValor) {
        this.camValor = camValor;
    }
    public int getValor() {
        return Valor;
    }
    public void setValor(int Valor) {
        this.Valor = Valor;
    }
    public int cambiaNumero(int camValor) {
        return Valor = camValor;
    }
```

Comment: El valor de que atributo? Puedes modificar el valor de "Valor" y "camValor" mediante los setters: setValor() y setCamValor(). Te recomiendo que sigas las convenciones de nombrado estandar y utilices notación camel case, es decir, "Valor" debería ser "valor".

Comment: Vampy95 explica a que te refieres con atributos porque en tu clase no hay atributos sino campos privados.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class miNumero {

public miNumero() {
    valor=0;
}

public int valor;

/**
 * Get the value of valor
 *
 * @return the value of valor
 */
public int getValor() {
    return valor;
}

/**
 * Set the value of valor
 *
 * @param valor new value of valor
 */
public void setValor(int valor) {
    this.valor = valor;
}

  public int cambiarNumero;

/**
 * Get the value of cambiarNumero
 *
 * @return the value of cambiarNumero
 */
public int getCambiarNumero() {
    return cambiarNumero;
}

/**
 * Set the value of cambiarNumero
 *
 * @param cambiarNumero new value of cambiarNumero
 */
public void setCambiarNumero(int cambiarNumero) {
    this.valor = cambiarNumero;
    this.cambiarNumero=valor;
}

}
```

Según la explicación, esto seria así.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto es a lo que te refieres

```
public class MiNumero {

private int Valor;
private int camValor;

public MiNumero() {         //Constructor sin parametros
    this.camValor = 0;      //Asignando valor de 0
}

public MiNumero(int numero) {    //Constructor con parametros
    this.camValor = numero;      //camValor recibe el valor del parametro numero
}

public int getCamValor() {
    return camValor;
}

public void setCamValor(int camValor) {
    this.camValor = camValor;
}

public int getValor() {
    return Valor;
}

public void setValor(int Valor) {
    this.Valor = Valor;
}

public int cambiaNumero(int camValor) {
    return Valor = camValor;
}
```

}

y luego en la clase principal solo cambias los JOptionpane por los scanner

```
public class Principal1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MiNumero miNumero = new MiNumero(); //Aqui se le asigna el valor de 0 a camValor        

    int num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba el valor"));

    MiNumero miNumero2 = new MiNumero(num);//Aqui se le asigna el valor de num a el constructor con parametro

    int nuevoNumero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba el nuevo valor"));

    miNumero.setCamValor(nuevoNumero);//se le envia el valor del nuevo numero a camValor
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

No se si tu pregunta es acerca de la variable camValor, pero si es así, es sencillo.

```
public static void Main(String args []){
Mi numero miNum = new MiNum();
miNum.setCamValor(valor);
}
```

Eso debiera de cambiar el valor de tu variable.

Pero si estas trabajando con Scanner o JOption:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String numero=br.readLine();
miNum.setCamValor(Integer.parseInt(numero));

String numero=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Inserte Numero");
miNum.setCamValor(Integer.parseInt(numero));
```

Comment: Trabajo con Scanner, el valor de la variable camValor se lo tengo que asignar mediante un scanner

Comment: Cuando trabajas con getters y setters, recuerda que el get es para mostrarte el valor y el set es para asignar y modificar.

Answer (score -1):

Lo tienes ahí, los métodos 'set' que te has creado te permiten cambiar el valor de tus atributos.

Te pongo un ejemplo de su aplicación:

```
//Creacion del objeto de la clase
MiNumero numero = new MiNumero();
//Puesto que no tienes constructor con paramétros, los atributos valor y camValor se inicializan a 0.

numero.setValor(5); //Esto cambia el valor del atributo valor de 0 a 5
numero.setCamValor(10); //Esto cambia el valor del atributo camValor de 0 a 10
```

Comment: Me he explicado mal, lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente: Escribe en Java una clase llamada MiNumero. Los métodos de la clase deben ser:
• Constructor sin parámetros (establecerá el número a cero)
• Constructor con parámetro entero (asignará ese valor al número)
• Método cambiaNumero(int): permite asignar un nuevo valor al número